# Download a JDK installer with wget in a batch file

Tags: java, eclipse, batch-file, command-line-interface, wget

Like said in the title, i'm trying to download the jdk installer in a batch file using the following command :

```
wget --verbose --show-progress --referer="https://download.oracle.com" --no-cookies --no-check-certificate --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" "https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/15.0.1%2B9/51f4f36ad4ef43e39d0dfdbaf6549e32/jdk-15.0.1_windows-x64_bin.exe"
```

I get this error from the batch file:

```
--2021-01-05 15:12:30--  https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/15.0.1B9/51f4f36ad4ef43e39d0dfdbaf6549e32/jdk-15.0.1_windows-x64_bin.exe
Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 23.212.156.99
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|23.212.156.99|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/15.0.1B9/51f4f36ad4ef43e39d0dfdbaf6549e32/jdk-15.0.1_windows-x64_bin.exe [following]
--2021-01-05 15:12:30--  https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/15.0.1B9/51f4f36ad4ef43e39d0dfdbaf6549e32/jdk-15.0.1_windows-x64_bin.exe
Resolving edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)... 2a02:26f0:2b00:3b4::366, 2a02:26f0:2b00:390::366, 104.124.198.35
Connecting to edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)|2a02:26f0:2b00:3b4::366|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/15.0.1B9/51f4f36ad4ef43e39d0dfdbaf6549e32/jdk-15.0.1_windows-x64_bin.exe?AuthParam=1609856056_4a223d45cbb97da535473401552470f5 [following]
--2021-01-05 15:12:31--  https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/15.0.1B9/51f4f36ad4ef43e39d0dfdbaf6549e32/jdk-15.0.1_windows-x64_bin.exe?AuthParam=1609856056_4a223d45cbb97da535473401552470f5
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|23.212.156.99|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2021-01-05 15:12:32 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

### **BUT**

When I use this command line directly in the CLI (changing the CD where the wget.exe file resides), it downloads the installer properly, like the following :

```
--2021-01-05 15:19:43--  https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/15.0.1%2B9/51f4f36ad4ef43e39d0dfdbaf6549e32/jdk-15.0.1_windows-x64_bin.exe
Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 23.212.156.99
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|23.212.156.99|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/15.0.1%2B9/51f4f36ad4ef43e39d0dfdbaf6549e32/jdk-15.0.1_windows-x64_bin.exe [following]
--2021-01-05 15:19:43--  https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/15.0.1%2B9/51f4f36ad4ef43e39d0dfdbaf6549e32/jdk-15.0.1_windows-x64_bin.exe
Resolving edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)... 2a02:26f0:2b00:390::366, 2a02:26f0:2b00:3b4::366, 104.126.235.187
Connecting to edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)|2a02:26f0:2b00:390::366|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/15.0.1+9/51f4f36ad4ef43e39d0dfdbaf6549e32/jdk-15.0.1_windows-x64_bin.exe?AuthParam=1609856489_c1f5f2310bf675762561de7d78160532 [following]
--2021-01-05 15:19:44--  https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/15.0.1+9/51f4f36ad4ef43e39d0dfdbaf6549e32/jdk-15.0.1_windows-x64_bin.exe?AuthParam=1609856489_c1f5f2310bf675762561de7d78160532
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|23.212.156.99|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 167452312 (160M) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: 'jdk-15.0.1_windows-x64_bin.exe'
```

I really need to use this command a script.

If anyone knew what could have gone wrong between the batch file and the CLI, I'd be really thankful for the help.

Comment: Just in case you don't know, [AdoptOpenJDK provides an API to download Java JREs/JDKs](https://api.adoptopenjdk.net/README).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare the URLs from your output.
The CLI URL contains a percentage sign `%2B` as part of a URL-encoded letter. But the batch script output is missing this percentage sign, therefore leading to a wrong URL.

- CLI output `15.0.1%2B9`
- Batch output `15.0.1B9`

Since batch uses the percentage sign `%` to identify variables you have to escape it, if you want to use it literally.

Therefore, try using two percentage signs in your batch script `%%`. This should lead to a (correct) single `%` in your URL.

Comment: It worked, I didn't think about this particular % character ! Thank you for pointing that out and for your help ! :)